# Why Vlfeat generates same number of descriptors for different images?

Tags: sift, vlfeat

I notice that Vlfeat/Sift generates same number of descriptors for different images, why?
And what is the aim of orientation assignment? It seems there is a similar process in the descriptor formation process. 
I am quite new to the SIFT and confused about a lot of stuff in SIFT. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Vlfeat/Sift generates same number of descriptors for different images, why?**

Except if you explicitly pass a file with [given input keypoints](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/sift.html#tut.sift.custom) (*) the number of descriptors is *NOT* the same and clearly depends on the input image content.

For example, if you compare the [Starbucks logo](https://www.google.com/search?q=starbucks+logo) with [Lena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna):

```
./sift --frames starbucks.pgm; wc -l starbucks.frame
 601 starbucks.frame

./sift --frames lena.pgm; wc -l lena.frame
1769 lena.frame
```

*Here I used 300x300 pixels images. The `--frames` outputs the keypoints found with one position, scale and orientation per line.*

(*) This means you ask VLFeat to describe a set of pre-defined interest points. With the `sift` VLFeat command line tool, you can do that with the `--read-frames` option.

**What is the aim of orientation assignment?**

This is to achieve rotation invariance. If you refer to the [original paper](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf):

> One or more orientations are assigned to each keypoint location based on local
>   image gradient directions. All future operations are performed on image data that 
>   has been transformed relative to the assigned orientation, scale, and location
>   for each feature, thereby providing invariance to these transformations.